# Using sed to modify Apache ports file

Tags: regex, apache, sed

I am trying to edit `Listen 80` in ports.conf file with sed.

Since that file looks like :

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

with this command:
head -n1 sed_test | sed -i -e 's/Listen [0-9]+/Listen 80/1p' sed_test

It changes all 'Listen $port_number' in the file. I guess it is because in second command I specify a file.

If I don't specify, to which file it should write, I get an error
`sed: no input files` which is logical although.

I know that it can be done only with a sed, but I am unsure how to edit only one line and replace it with my custom value.

So this is what I want to accomplish:

**sed -i -e *some_command/Listen 8080* file**

**cat file** ->

```
 Listen 8080

    <IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
    </IfModule>
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This **can** be done with standard `sed`:

```
sed '/Listen/{s/\([0-9]\+\)/8080/; :a;n; ba}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `gnu sed` you can use:

```
sed -i '0,/Listen [0-9]*/s//Listen 8080/' file

Listen 8080

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

If you don't have `gnu sed` then you can use `awk` to replace only first instance:

```
awk '!p{ p=sub(/Listen [0-9]*/, "Listen 8080") } 1' file

Listen 8080

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Comment: That is what I needed. :-)
Thanks!